# When should security annotation 'denyAll' be used?

Tags: java, security, annotations

In what situations is annotation [`javax.annotation.security.DenyAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/DenyAll.html) useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its can be used for a method which must be public for some reason (perhaps it implements an interface) but should never be called directly.  It can be called from other methods in the same entity.

http://openejb.apache.org/security-annotations.html